# Can we use gravitational wave to detect which slit electron pass through?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, gravitational-waves

Just in principle, in a double slit experiment, is it possible to use gravitational wave to determined which slit did an electron go through?

I am honestly don't know, and it just a question that comes to my mind. 
P.S. I did try to find some references on this, but did not found any that given a satisfying answer.

Comment: Are you wondering if it makes a difference if the "which slit" detector doesn't interact electromagnetically with the electron?

Comment: In some sense, yeah.

Comment: *I did try to find some references on this* … A good starting point would be this [essay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.04496).

Answer (score -5):

There is no device to genuinely measure Gravitational Waves as a "Quanta" we see the effects to document it's proof. The First observation of gravitational waves was announced in 2015. Question is can so few photons be observed Large ground experiments have.  [image]

Double slit experiments have used and tested for Gravity waves. Gravitational waves weren't first detected til 2015.
https://vixra.org/pdf/1602.0168v1.pdf

Comment: this seems to be copied from  https://vixra.org/pdf/1602.0168v1.pdf